# GNU Screen: you have neither usable sockets nor usable pipes

Tags: compiling, gnu-screen

I am trying to build GNU screen on CentOS 6 Minimal and 
When I type the command `./configure`

it gives me this error

> you have neither usable sockets nor usable pipes -> no screen

I tried to use `yum update` and `yum provide */stropts.h`

Still gives me the same error

when I type the command `make` it gives me that error

> pty.c:38:26: error: sys/stropts.h: No such file or directory

How should I solve it?

Pleas don't answer 
use `yum install screen`

Comment: That's part of libc. I'd assume you don't have basic C software development headers installed. On Debian, that'd be libc6-dev. Is there some way you can ask yum for the build dependencies of screen?

Comment: May I ask why you're building it? Just for fun or b/c you need to install it?

Answer (score 2):

On Redhat based distros it's often easier to install a group of tools for a particular task rather than try and guess what one might need. You can use `yum` to get the list of groups that are availble.

```
$ yum groups list
```

You can limit this list to developer types of groups like this:

```
$ yum groups list | grep -i dev
   Development and Creative Workstation
   C Development Tools and Libraries
   Development Tools
   RPM Development Tools
```

To install:

```
$ sudo yum groups install "C Development Tools and Libraries"
```

This group of packages should cover *most* of the opensource software you'll try and install. There will of course be outliers. If you encounter missing libraries you'll need to install the binary form of the library and the headers (for compilation).

#### Example

For the library `libmng` there are 4 packages available.

```
$ rpm -aq | grep libmn
libmng-devel-1.0.10-11.fc19.x86_64
libmng-1.0.10-11.fc19.x86_64
libmng-1.0.10-11.fc19.i686
libmnl-1.0.3-5.fc19.x86_64
```

So you'll need to install these types of packages to do a compilation. The libraries are always named `<lib name>` and the corresponding headers are named `<lib name>-devel` on Redhat distros.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to build screen by this way and worked successfully

screen depends on library termcap so install it

then vi the file that gives the error and comment that line `#include <sys/stropts.h>`

so it works like this

```
vi tty.c
```

then comment the line which includes sys/stropts.h on every file that gives the error

then `make` if make gives this error just repeat the process until no errors appear